# What's the most efficient firework booster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am just getting started with firework boosters and elytra in survival mode.

Say I have 64 gunpowder and 64 paper. Will I achieve the most distance by crafting them into 192 duration 1 fireworks, 96 duration 2 fireworks, or 64 duration 3 fireworks?

Comment: I think xisuma made a video about this on youtube

Comment: all fireworks boost you at the same speed, so the only factor to determine how efficient they are is how long they boost. duration 1 fireworks are the best in this context

Comment: @XeroOl That is false, as explained in Xisuma's video you gave - (Watch videos you post) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShwFl2caKc0

Answer (score 3):

You're using the same number of resources either way, but your stated objective dictates quality of firework achieves your goal.

64 duration 3 has the most propellant thus most distance (height) in a single shot before detonating; its like 3 fireworks (64*3=192).

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/5iik86/the_firework_elytra_combo_is_awesome/) users report a duration 3 gets you about 80 blocks, so more frequent landings with lower duration not only takes longer in a cumulative sense, but though resource use is identical either way, you effectively keep flight longer and faster from greater height with a duration 3

Comment: The part of using the same number of resources isn't true with the difference being paper. Paper required for crafting is only 1 in each recipe, so 3 duration 1 rockets need 3 paper, whereas 1 duration 3 rocket needs 1 paper.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a duration 3 firework is the same as 3 duration 1 fireworks, so it uses less paper, but you have less control. So if you're fine with having a firework last longer, then by all means do it, but if you want more control, then use 1 gunpowder. you could also do a duration 2 rocket for a balance.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I did a test. I went into a flat world tp'd myself so I looked up at a 25 degree angle, and used each rocket without changing the angle, I flew in a straight line. This is very slow once decending, but can show us an accurate estimation of how much of a difference eacht duration makes.

Duration 1: 348.769 blocks = 348.769 blocks/gunpowder
Duration 2: 426.148 blocks = 213.074 blocks/gunpowder
Duration 3: 463.582 blocks = 154.527 blocks/gunpowder

With this test, duration 1 is obviously the best. You also don't have to spend 3 gunpowder just to fly 100 blocks when using duration 1 fireworks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say 192 duration 1 fireworks. Although duration 3 fireworks last longer, you don't have enough. Let's say you want to dive off a cliff every morning in Minecraft, and you use 2 duration 3 rockets every time (one there, one back). You can only have 32 flights, but if all you want to do is get off the ground and stay in the air, I say quantity is key.